# Saltstack regular expression to target all except

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble using regex with salt to target every minion except one.

I have tried every example I can find and exhausted my limited understanding of Perl regex. I expect this to target every minion (all named something.domain.co.uk):

```
^(?!.*mail).*$
```

However it returns zero values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear to me... Any examples of things you want to match and things you don't want to match?

Comment: Sorry Jerry, I want to match everything except mail.domain.co.uk. The other servers are web.domain.co.uk, edi.domain.co.uk, forum.domain.co.uk, etc.

Comment: Okay, are you using the `-E` option?

Comment: I was unaware of an -E option. Running "salt -E '^(?!.*mail).*$' test.ping" does return the correct minions. But I need this in the top.sls file, can I include -E there?

Comment: Well, I didn't know what was saltstack and a search led me to [this page](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/globbing.html) where it mentions regular expression and used `-E`. And for your next question, I have absolutely no idea, sorry =/

Comment: The answer was to include:

    - match: pcre

in the top.sls file.

Comment: You can put an answer with everything that was needed. It's fine to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

[PCRE Minion_ID Compound Matcher](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html) denoted by `E@` is what you want.

When targeting minions on the command line:

```
salt -C 'E@^(foo|bar)$' test.ping
```

Or in a top file:

```
base:
  'E@^(?!.*mail).*$':
    - match: compound
```

Yes, you can use `salt -E 'regex'` or `- match: pcre` and skip the leading `E@` for pure minion_id regex, but chaining multiple matchers (grains PCRE, cidr ip block, etc) can be quite expressive:

```
 salt -C 'G@os:(Ubuntu|Debian) and G@domain:example\.(com|net) and E@^(?!.*mail).*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your top.sls, use the following syntax to match:

```
base:
  '^(?!.*mail).*$':
    - match: pcre
    - states_to_apply
```

Source: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/globbing.html